# How to use JavaScriptCore in React Native android apps

Tags: react-native, javascriptcore

We are building a React Native application on Android. We have a requirement of creating a separate JSC virtual machine instance in a thread. We do not want to use same JSC context which is used by React Native.

We have searched a lot on web and also tried to figure out how React Native is using JSC, but we are not able to find the same.

It will be very helpful if anyone can suggest us directions for the same.

Comment: Have you made some progress? I'm also interested in running JSC VM in Android Service. So executing js will be not depended on Android Activity.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Perhaps you should take a look at this:

[ericwlange/AndroidJSCore](https://github.com/ericwlange/AndroidJSCore)

or dive deep into React Native's Android source code.

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/ReactAndroid/src/main/jni/react/JSCExecutor.cpp

Comment: Note that the first link says "AndroidJSCore is currently unsupported". And the second link is broken, that file was moved to https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/ReactCommon/cxxreact/JSCExecutor.cpp.

Comment: **UPDATE 2018:** AndroidJSCore has been superseded by [LiquidCore](https://github.com/LiquidPlayer/LiquidCore), which is based on V8.  Not only does it include the V8 engine, but all of Node.js is available as well.